# Can't focus on JTextField in JDialog

Tags: java, swing, focus, jtextfield, jdialog

I'm trying to focus on a JTextField in a JDialog; I've tried all the suggestions in [this link](http://tips4java.wordpress.com/2010/03/14/dialog-focus/) after poking around for similar questions, but none of the suggestions worked.

The component I'm trying to focus on is created in a class called "InputTaskWindow", and I'm trying to create a dialog from a class called "MainWindow". Here's where the issue is (This is within "MainWindow"):

```
public  class NewTask extends AbstractAction {

JList mTaskList;
JTextArea mDetailsTextArea;

public NewTask (JList tl, JTextArea dta){
    mTaskList = tl;
    mDetailsTextArea = dta;
}

public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
    int option = 0;
    InputTaskWindow inputTaskWindow = new InputTaskWindow();
    JOptionPane optionPane = new JOptionPane(inputTaskWindow.createComponents(), JOptionPane.PLAIN_MESSAGE, JOptionPane.OK_CANCEL_OPTION);

    JDialog dialog = optionPane.createDialog("New Task");

    dialog.setSize(200, 200);

    dialog.pack();

    ((JTextField) inputTaskWindow.getComponent(inputTaskWindow.NAMETF)).requestFocus();

    dialog.setVisible(true);

    if (optionPane.getValue() != null){
        option = (Integer)optionPane.getValue();
    }

    if (option == JOptionPane.OK_OPTION){
        Task t = inputTaskWindow.getTask();
        activeDay.addTask(t);
    }

    populateLists(mTaskList);
}
```

I put the JTextField I'm trying to access in an array of JComponents in the GUI class; I've accessed other components using the getComponents() method, so I know that's pointing to the correct thing.

I've tried requestFocus(), requestFocusInWindow(), adding an ancestorListener in the NewTask class, and adding an ancestorListener upon the creation of the JTextField in InputTaskWindow (in both cases I'm adding it to the JTextField and using the RequestFocusListener class described in the link). Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: I think you should fix your naming conventions so it's easier to read. Apart from that, instead of invoking `requestFocus`, try invoking `setFocusable(true)`.

Comment: I don't see where you try to add `JTextField` to `JDialog`

Comment: Maxim: I don't add it directly, actually; its in a JPanel created in InputTaskWindow, which is passed to the dialog in createComponents(). Do I need to focus on the JPanel first?

Comment: you are right, common issue, solved here a few times, different ways

Comment: mKorbel: So I tried focusing on the JPanel first, but it still doesn't work. I've also seen this posted before, which is part of why I'm so confused. None of those fixes seem to do anything. Clearly I'm missing something. I'll keep digging.

Comment: Post your `SSCCE` that demonstrates the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I haven't determined what the problem is, but I've decided to abandon this code. I strongly suspect the problem has to do with a refresh function, not a misunderstanding of focus methods (my first assumption). The code is too tangled to warrant sorting out, so I'm considering the question closed.